# How to prevent the outer class method from accessing privately defined methods or fields of a nested class?

Tags: java

I am attempting to prevent the `OuterMethod` from accessing the privately-defined field `InnerField` and method `InnerMethod`. It does not seem to work as what I expect.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Outer {

    void OuterMethod() {
        Inner.InnerMethod();
        out.println(new Inner().InnerField);
    }

    private final static class Inner {
        private final int InnerField = 20;

        private static void InnerMethod() {
            out.println("Inner Method");
        }
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Outer().OuterMethod();
    }
}
```

### Question

How to prevent the outer class method from accessing privately defined methods or fields of a nested class?

Comment: You’ll have to not use Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  Java says so.

From the [Java Language Specification, section 6.6.1, Determining Accessibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6):

> Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared private, and access
> is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level
> class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or
> constructor.

And, really, it would not make a lot of sense to restrict access. The outer class programmer is in full control of the inner class; he can exercise restraint if he so chooses.

Otherwise, promote the inner class to the top level.

Comment: Thank you. It means that defining setter and getter in a nested class will be useless.

Comment: @WhoSaveMeSaveEntireWorld Not useless; if a nested class defines _JavaBean properties_, those may be interpreted by lots of Java tooling.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-: Thank you very much. A good point!

Comment: Well, if you want my unpopular opinion, most setters that just do `{ this.thing = thing }` are close to worthless in any case, since in practical terms they're equivalent to an assignment (with no validity checking, concurrency control, etc.)   This is encapsulation in flimsy cling-film.  This is not an argument against setters, it's am argument against setters that exercise no control over setting.

Comment: *It means that defining setter and getter in a nested class will be useless.*  Not really.  They offer the advantage of being able to manipulate the data prior to returning it or setting it.  You may still want defensive copies and such before getting the data (to protect you from yourself).  And they also allow you to employ method references in some stream applications.  But inner classes are very much related to their enclosing class so restriction access to the private fields and methods doesn't make sense.